# Strange rewriterule difficulty - what am i doing wrong

Tags: drupal, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, drupal-6

I am trying to rewrite everything by appending a language code at the beginning of the path. When I use this: `RewriteRule ^(.*)3$ es/$1`
browsing `mysite.com/admin3` properly loads `mysite.com/es/admin`.

But i do not know why, but when I use this: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ es/$1`

browsing `mysite.com/admin` does load `mysite.com/es/admin` BUT it loads so slow, and in plain html (no css, no images, etc).

Can somebody point out what am I doing wrong? It's driving me nuts - i', a regexp noob.

Thanks.

---

UPDATE:
We already have a multilingual site running. But we wanted to provide alternative access to the other languages via local domains. So we wanted to have `mysite.com/es` while having `newdomain.es` at the same time. This is not possible via Drupal's "domain name" language negotiation.

Now I've already setup `newdomain.es/es` but I want users to only see `newdomain.es` on the address bar.

Comment: Since you are using drupal, why don't you use internationlization ( http://drupal.org/project/i18n ) ? For as far I know there is a module that does exactly what you want...

Comment: i do use it and it works well. But we wanted to separate the languages via local domains. so `mysite.com/es` will become `newsite.es` etc. I wanted to users to see `newsite.es` when they are actually browsing `newsite.es/es`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having was that, files are also forwarded (e.g, css, javascript, images, etc). This is how I solved it:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.es$ [NC]
# optional: add other language exceptions so they still work
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fr/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ es/$1 [NC,QSA]

# for homepage
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.es$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ es
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realised that one could use the subdomain option from Drupal internationlisation under `/admin/config/regional/language/configure`.

If you choose [configure] next to URL, you can enable domain prefix like `es.mysite.com`.

And then you can point your DNS of `mysite.es` to `es.mysite.com`. Just add to DNS of `mysite.es` the value `www - CNAME - es.mysite.com` (Note that sometimes you might need an extra dot in the destination like `www - CNAME - es.mysite.com.`).

Comment: language negotiation is not an option. It will not allow me to use other languages on `mysite.es`, e.g. `mysite.es/en`. But I appreciate the help. Thanks!